# Altering the tables in a database dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two database:
-Pre-staging Database: This has a prefix CCPREST_
-Staging Database: This has a prefix CCST_

There are few entities in both the database say:
In CCPREST we have CCPREST_Employees table
In CCST we have CCST_Employees table

Now this Staging table keeps on adding/removing some entites from the database. This also includes adding some extra columns in the tables.

List of Columns in CCPREST_Employees:
EmpdID,EmpName,Salary,Address,PhoneNumber

List of Columns in CCST_Empployees:
EmpdID,EmpName,Salary,Address,PhoneNumber,Country_Ext,GeoLocation_Ext

These extra two columns Country_Ext,GeoLocation_Ext has to be included in the CCPREST_Employees table as well. In this way there are many entites in the CCPREST database where we need to add the extra columns from CCST database.

I have written the below query to identify the extra columns:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP from    (SELECT A.TABLE_NAME [CCPREST_TABLES],A.COLUMN_NAME [CCPREST_COLUMNS],
B.TABLE_NAME [CCST_TABLES],B.COLUMN_NAME[CCST_COLUMNS],
B.DATA_TYPE [CCST_DATATYPES],B.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH [CCST_SIZE],B.IS_NULLABLE [CCST_ISNULLABLE]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A --ccprest tables
    FULL OUTER JOIN [STG_Extract Database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B --ccst tables
    ON (A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
        AND SUBSTRING(A.TABLE_NAME,9,LEN(A.TABLE_NAME)) = SUBSTRING(B.TABLE_NAME,6,LEN(B.TABLE_NAME)
        ))
WHERE B.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'CCST%') as X
```

This will give the below result:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjo55.jpg)

Now I am trying to write a dynamic SQL which will create multiple ALTER statements to update the CCPREST_COLUMNS with CCST_COLUMNS

```
select 'alter table '+CASE WHEN CCPREST_TABLES IS NULL THEN REPLACE(CCST_TABLES,'CCST','CCPREST')END+' add '+ccst_columns+' '+ccst_datatypes+'('+CCST_SIZE+')'
```

from #temp

But this gives an error of some incorrect syntax.
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ')'' to data type int.

Can anyone help me out in framing the ALTER statement correctly ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly cast the length as a string to avoid implicit conversion and handle datatypes without a length specification. The example below will work for the varchar and int data types in your case but needs to be extended to properly handle other types like decimal (with precision and scale) and datetime2, time, datetimeoffset (with precision) if your tables may contain those types.

```
SELECT 'alter table '
    + CASE WHEN CCPREST_TABLES IS NULL THEN REPLACE(CCST_TABLES,'CCST','CCPREST') END
    +' add '+ccst_columns+' '+ccst_datatypes+COALESCE('('+CAST(CCST_SIZE AS varchar(10))+')','')
FROM #temp;
```